# No Bottom Scroll Bar on Native Mode SSRS 2012 with IE11 (IE5 document mode)

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to get a couple of features of SSRS working in IE11.  The two features are:
-Floating Bottom Scroll Bar (pan left and right when report content wider than ie window)
-Frozen Column Headers (headers float above columns when scrolling down a report)

When put into standard compatibility mode, or forcing specific legacy document modes (ie7 - ie9), frozen column headers don't work, and the bottom scroll bar is only visible when scrolling to the very bottom of the report.

When forcing IE5 Quirks mode, the column headers float as desired, but the bottom scroll bar disappears completely.

Any ideas for how to get both features to work in IE11?

**Note:**
Both features do work in Sharepoint Integrated Mode (SP 2013), but we do not want to rely on SP for our reporting.

**UPDATE:**

I was previously working off a faulty assumption that the reports were working fully in Native Mode on the old server, in fact the bottom scroll bar does not show up on the old server.  I found that, on the old server, the  had been removed from the ReportViewer.aspx which was automatically forcing IE5 Quirks mode, this caused the floating headers to work.  Now, at least, I can reproduce the behavior.

I've rewritten the above description to narrow down the issue.

Comment: DO they work when you navigate to the site and select Tools|Compadibility Settings and add your url?

Comment: As I mentioned above, compatibility mode does not fully resolve the issue, compatibility view shows a bottom scroll bar when you scroll all the way to the bottom of the report.  Forcing "IE5 Quirks mode" via legacy document mode (<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" ?> )  enables the floating headers, but there is no bottom scroll bar to be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with some customizations that were made to the ReportViewer.aspx file, issue was resolved by adding "padding-bottom" to the form element with ID "ReportViewerPage" using js.